# Shouldrasterize performance depends on number of sublayers (but it should not)

Tags: core-animation

I have a complex UIView with a lot of sublayers. To smooth my animation i make shouldrasterize = true before scaling on my ROOT layer.

However I notice that performance is still poor when there are a lot of elements visible. And it becomes better if there are less sublayers on the screen at the moment.

This strikes me as wrong. If the whole picture is a bitmap, not vector, then the performance should be the same no matter how much sublayers there are on the screen.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to turn on shouldrasterize in such a way that the picture would scale fast no matter how many sublayers there are?

Thank you.